# Why I can't write int to vector

Tags: c++, vector

My input is:

```
4 4 
4 8 7 3 
2 5 9 3 
6 3 2 5 
4 4 1 6
```

A program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {
  int rows, columns;
  std::cin >> rows >> columns;
  std::vector<int> map(rows);
  int cell;

  for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
    for (int column = 0; column < columns; ++column) {
      std::cin >> cell;
      map[row].push_back(cell);
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to compile the program I've got an error message:

```
app.cpp:16:15: error: member reference base type 'value_type' (aka 'int')
      is not a structure or union
      map[row].push_back(cell);
      ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't understand why it's happened?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ `map` declared as vector of `ints`. You couldn't push back `std::vector` in vectors of ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
std::vector<int> map(rows);
```

you declare vector of ints with length rows. As I understand from you code, you need a vector of vectors. Probably you need something like

```
  int rows, columns;
  std::cin >> rows >> columns;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> map(rows);
  int cell;

  for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
    map[row].resize(columns);
    for (int column = 0; column < columns; ++column) {
      std::cin >> cell;
      map[row][column] = cell;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you want that call to `resize()` in the outer loop or possibly meant to call `reserve()` instead.

Comment: Did you mean `map[row] = cell;` or `reserve` instead of `resize`?

Comment: @Blastfurnace, @Mohit Jain What is the difference between `reserve` and `resize` in this case? Both of them resize vector to desired size.

Comment: @Mohit Jain In my code `map[row]` is `std::vector<int>`, and `cell` is an `int`. Therefore, I push back new `int` to vector `map[row]`.

Comment: @kvorobiev: If you call `resize` it constructs that many elements and the subsequent calls to `push_back` add __additional__ elements.

Comment: O, sorry to all, it's my mistake. I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `std::vector<int> map(rows);` with

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > map(rows);
```

`std::vector<int> map(rows);`: map is a vector with `rows` elements and typeof `map[row]` is an `int`, so you can not apply `push_back` to it.

`std::vector< std::vector<int> > map(rows);`: map is a vector of vectors with `rows` elemetns and typeof `map[row]` is `vector<int>` and you can apply `push_back` to it.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you are going to have a two-dimensional table. However you defined only a "row":

```
std::vector<int> map(rows);
```

that is a vector of a sequence of integers.

You have to define a vector of vectors of integers.

The code could look the following way

```
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

int main () 
{
    int rows, columns;

    std::cin >> rows >> columns;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> map;
    map.reserve( rows );

    for ( int row = 0; row < rows; ++row ) 
    {
        std::vector<int> tmp;
        tmp.reserve( columns );   

        for ( int column = 0; column < columns; ++column ) 
        {
            int cell;

            std::cin >> cell;
            tmp.push_back( cell );
        }
        map.push_back( tmp );
    }
}
```